# Selecting first n columns and last n columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select the first 2 columns and the last 2 column from a data frame by index with pandas and save it on the same dataframe.

is there a way to do that in one step?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `iloc` function to get the columns, and then pass in the indexes.

```
df.iloc[:,[0,1,-1,-2]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7]], columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])

df.iloc[:,:2] # Grabs all rows and first 2 columns
df.iloc[:,-2:] # Grabs all rows and last 2 columns

pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:2],df.iloc[:,-2:]],axis=1) # Puts them together row wise
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7]], columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])

df[['a','b','d','e']]
```

result

```
    a   b   d   e
0   1   2   4   5
1   2   3   5   6
2   3   4   6   7
```

Comment: I have 19 columns and they are  Unnamed